# Searching for data from database does not search the term in java?

Tags: java, request-mapping, http-request-parameters

So, my problem is I have a api I am creating an I am getting data from database. So, when I do GET `localhost:8080/myapp/jobs?autocomplete=0120` (which 0120 is the full value of the jobs code to show that data, which it does show that data). But, when I do `localhost:8080/myapp/jobs?autocomplete=012` it wont show what data it has for `012` to display in json. Can anyone help me solve this issue with my code below. thanks!

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/jobs")
    public List<AutoComplete> getSalary( @PathVariable("autocomplete") String autocomplete, @RequestParam(value = "jobClassCd", defaultValue = "1502") String jobClassCd) {

        return autoCompleteService.retrieveSalary(jobClassCd);
    }
```

Comment: are 012 and 0120 both similar?

Comment: yes. But, you understand what I want to accomplish, right?

Comment: I think you want the same result for 012 as you are getting for 0120. am I right?

Comment: yes. But, even if I search 012, try to find values that start from 012 to list them. Just like a front end looking autocomplete search input.

Comment: why don't you try to change your query and use Like query.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194902/discussion-between-vishal-patel-and-jay-a).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to write a query that does something like

**select * from  AutoComplete where jobClassCd like 012%**

Change your repository method as below.

```
@Repository 
public interface AutoCompleteRepository extends CrudRepository<AutoComplete, String> { 

    @Query("select e from AutoComplete e where jobClassCd like ':jobClassCd%'") 
    List<AutoComplete> findByJobClassCd(@Param("jobClassCd") String jobClassCd); 


    @Query("select e from AutoComplete e") 
    public Stream<AutoComplete> streamAll(); 
}
```